# Moving an html element back and forth with javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, html, click, actionlistener, move

I have never used JavaScript to write a function that interacts with HTML elements so I was hoping I could get some help.
I have an image that will be clicked.  I want to move it from its current position either left or right depending on how it last moved.

For example, the first time it's clicked it will move to the left, second to the right, and so forth.  Here is the html and css code for the element:

The transform is just for centering.

Here is the javascript I have written so far; at this point nothing happens when the div is clicked:

```js
var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
var dir = -1;
var diff = 50;

function toMove(){
    for(int i=0; i<diff; i++){
        logo.style.left += ""+ dir +"px";
        window.setTimeout(100);
    }
    dir  = dir*-1;
}
```

```css
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
<a onclick="toMove()">
    <img src = "mypic.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
```

The part I have commented out was the first option I tried that didn't work.  Can anybody tell me what my problem is?
Thanks!!

UPDATE:
Edited the script to only use on function toMove() that operates on the dir variable.  Also modified the HTML to use an  wrapper around the img to call the function directly instead of using an actionlistener on the div.  Also, I don't think I clarified very well initially, the idea is to create a smooth transition across the screen, rather than simply resetting the location immediately.  The code still doesn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: You are missing an opening `{` here: `else moveRight(move)
   }`

Comment: Clicking "TIDY" in your snippet shows at least one error

Comment: * Use window.onload to access the DOM after load. * Your functions are wrong. Perhaps you mean `function moveLeft(n) {
  var left = parseInt(logo.style.left);
  if (left - 1 > left - n) window.setTimeout(moveLeft, 100);
  logo.style.left = (left - 1) + 'px';
}`

Comment: @mplungjan where would I put the window.onload in the code?  I'm thinking that may be my problem.

Comment: `var logo; window.onload=function() { logo = document.getElementById("logo"); }' makes logo global in scope but not accessed until after it exists

Answer (score 0):

you can use getBoundingClientRect() method to get the left position and try something like this:

```js
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
var num = 1;
var move = 40;
var offsets = document.getElementById('logo').getBoundingClientRect();
logo.onclick = function() {

  if (num < 0)
    moveLeft(move);

  else moveRight(move)
}


function moveLeft(n) {
  logo.style.left = offsets.left - n + 'px';
  num = 1;

}

function moveRight(n) {
  logo.style.left = offsets.left + n + 'px';
  num = -1;
}
```

```css
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anonymous unfortunately that only works to set the element to the offset immediately but I'm looking for a smooth transition.  Any way you could help me with that?  I modified my code to make it more streamlined but it still doesn't work.  I have a feeling it has something to do with the for loop but I'm not sure.

Comment: didn't mean to edit your code, I thought I was editing my own lol